# Best practicce to refresh data on LCD

Tags: adc, arm, lcd

I am currently reading value from ADC and displaying on LCD screen. The ADC is supported by DMA. Now my system has 5 menus seen on LCD (Voltage, Current, Resistance, Settings). 3 of them should display ADC value with ~ 1fps.

What are the best practices to refresh the LCD frames?

Shall I implement a timer and refresh the whole LCD screen on every overflow?
Or should I just refresh that number?

Or shomehow else?

What are the best pracitces of building menus?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for updating an LCD depends upon a variety of factors including how much RAM is available, the speed of communication to the LCD controller, what sorts of updates the controller can accommodate, and the extent to which the screen can be logically divided into non-overlapping rectangular regions which may be handled separately.  No single approach will be optimal for all situations.

The most important aspect of trying to get clean-looking updates is probably ensuring that any region which holds particular content before an update, and should hold that same content after the update, will hold that same content throughout the update.  If you erase a region of the screen and then draw in it the stuff that was already there, that's apt to be noticeable.  It's much better to either leave alone the parts of the screen that won't change, or else ensure that they are never drawn with anything other than their final content.

An approach that I've sometimes found helpful is to divide the screen into strips, and have a RAM buffer that's large enough to handle two strips.  Things can be drawn in chunks that are one strip high, overlapping the two buffers.  Then send one buffer, copy the lower one to the upper one and clear the lower one, and repeat.  The entire "draw screen" routine gets repeated for each strip, but functions whose effects are entirely outside the current strip return quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application and the LCD.

If most of the screen changes regularly (e.g. waveforms or images), then writing all at once x times a second is the "usual" way to go. You can double buffer and be setting up the next frame as the current one is writing - your DMA may be able to switch between the buffers automatically. If it's only 1 FPS, and you have a few things changing then I think I'd keep it simple and just update it all every second.

If you only have a small portion updating (e.g a few digits on a static background) then it may be more economical to just update this area and leave the rest. You can even do a difference check between the two frames and only alter the pixels that need to be changed if you want to be as economical as possible with the writes.
Different displays have different features for selecting bits of the display, and memory options for buffering. Some can have quite complex and useful features, and others are very simple and not so flexible.

Depending on how often they have new data and if there is a "menu only" part of your application, you may want to use the above option for your menus, and just update these as necessary when something changes. So a combination of both options could be used (assuming you have waveforms and menus)